# I18n Rails 3.2 Missing translation in admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I use Rails 3.2 and I work on Internationalization project. I have not translated the administrator part but this error is displayed 
Please if anyone knows this error:

> translation missing: en.support.array.words_connector

[image: http://postimg.org/image/609qsrqvd/]

Answer (score 0):

Check in your project folder `config/locales/en.yml` file. It has to contain translations errors occurring on.

```
en:
 support:
  array:
   words_connector:
    glasses_arms: 'translation here'
```

etc

Comment: thanks :)) 
I found the solution , you're right I used the key support for another thing , 
it is oriented by default for admin Support, i just change this key and it's works